# Throw exception to main acivity from Dialog

Tags: android, exception, handle, throw

I'm coding an android application must catch in the main activity all throwed exceptions and send email to me. But in some areas in my application i can't just throw the exception by the method :

Example : onCreateDialog() in a custom DialogFragment :

```
    builder.setView(addCatLayout)
                    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    try {
                                    // Save some data in DB here
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // Close the dialog window
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
            return builder.create();
```

My question how can i remove try catch block from this method and throw directly the exception to be catched in my main activity ? I want to have only one try catch block in the main activity that's catch all exceptions and sends mail to me. It's this possible ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can do this by throwing an unchecked exception. So an exception that inherits from RuntimeException.  Exceptions like that, don't have to be catched (Checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the dialog in activity and want to handle the Exception there

activity:

```
protected void handleException(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

OnClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    try {
        // Save some data in DB here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        handleException(e); // methods are visible to nested classes
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
 }
```

If you are creating the dialog outside activity, then you should

```
public void handleException(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Dialog creating class

```
public static void createDialog(final YourActivity activity) {

....

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        try {
            // Save some data in DB here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            activity.handleException(e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
     }


}
```

But that way it is a better practice to make your Activity implement some interface, like

```
public final class YourActivity implements ExceptionHandler {
```

Where the Exception handler is

```
public interface ExceptionHandler {
    void handleException(Exception e);
}
```

And pass the Exception handler interface

```
public void createDialog(final ExceptionHandler handler) {
```

Comment: Thank you ! i created the interface it's a good idea to handle exceptions this way.